# Location of documentation on special methods recognized by numpy

Tags: python, numpy

One of the differences between `math.exp` and `numpy.exp` is that, if you have a custom class `C` that has a `C.exp` method, `numpy.exp` will notice and delegate to this method whereas `math.exp` will not:

```
class C:
    def exp(self):
        return 'hey!'

import math
math.exp(C())  # raises TypeError
import numpy
numpy.exp(C())  # evaluates to 'hey!'
```

However, if you go to the [web documentation of `numpy.exp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.exp.html), this seems to be taken for granted. It isn't explicitly stated anywhere. Is there a place where this functionality is documented?

More generally, is there a place with a list of *all* such methods recognized by numpy?

Answer (score 4):

This isn't a special behavior of the `np.exp` function; it's just a consequence of how object dtype arrays are evaluated.

`np.exp` like many numpy functions tries to convert non-array inputs into arrays before acting.

```
In [227]: class C:
     ...:     def exp(self):
     ...:         return 'hey!'
     ...:     
In [228]: np.exp(C())
Out[228]: 'hey!'

In [229]: np.array(C())
Out[229]: array(<__main__.C object at 0x7feb7154fa58>, dtype=object)
In [230]: np.exp(np.array(C()))
Out[230]: 'hey!'
```

So `C()` is converted into an array, which is an object dtype *(`C()` isn't an iterable like `[1,2,3]`).  Typically a numpy function, if given an object dtype array, iterates on the elements, asking each to perform the corresponding method.  That explains how [228] ends up evaluating `C().exp()`.

```
In [231]: np.exp([C(),C()])
Out[231]: array(['hey!', 'hey!'], dtype=object)
In [232]: np.exp([C(),C(),2])
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-232-5010b59d525d> in <module>()
----> 1 np.exp([C(),C(),2])

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

`np.exp` can work on an array object dtype provided all the elements have a `exp` method.  Integers don't.  `ndarray` doesn't either.

```
In [233]: np.exp([C(),C(),np.array(2)])
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

`math.exp` expects a number, an Python scalar (or something that can convert into a scalar such as `np.array(3)`.

I expect this behavior is common to all`ufunc`.  I don't know about other numpy functions that don't follow that protocol.

In some cases the `ufunc` delegates to `__` methods:

```
In [242]: class C:
     ...:     def exp(self):
     ...:         return 'hey!'
     ...:     def __abs__(self):
     ...:         return 'HEY'
     ...:     def __add__(self, other):
     ...:         return 'heyhey'
     ...:     
In [243]: 
In [243]: np.abs(C())
Out[243]: 'HEY'
In [244]: np.add(C(),C())
Out[244]: 'heyhey'
```