# Sympy-numpy integration exists - where is it documented?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I just accidentally discovered that I can mix sympy expressions up with numpy arrays:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import sympy as sym
>>> x, y, z = sym.symbols('x y z')
>>> np.ones(5)*x
array([1.0*x, 1.0*x, 1.0*x, 1.0*x, 1.0*x], dtype=object)
# I was expecting this to throw an error!

# sum works and collects terms etc. as I would expect
>>> np.sum(np.array([x+0.1,y,z+y]))
x + 2*y + z + 0.1
# dot works too
>>> np.dot(np.array([x,y,z]),np.array([z,y,x]))
2*x*z + y**2
>>> np.dot(np.array([x,y,z]),np.array([1,2,3]))
x + 2*y + 3*z
```

This is quite useful for me, because I'm doing both numerical and symbolic calculations in the same program. However, I'm curious about the pitfalls and limitations of this approach --- it seems for example that neither `np.sin` nor `sym.sin` are supported on Numpy arrays containing Sympy objects, since both give an error.

However, this numpy-sympy integration doesn't appear to be documented anywhere. Is it just an accident of how these libraries are implemented, or is it a deliberate feature? If the latter, when is it designed to be used, and when would it be better to use `sympy.Matrix` or other solutions? Can I expect to keep some of numpy's speed when working with arrays of this kind, or will it just drop back to Python loops as soon as a sympy symbol is involved?

In short I'm pleased to find this feature exists, but I would like to know more about it!

Comment: You can check sympy-numpy compatibility [tests](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/external/tests/test_numpy.py)

Comment: @bro-grammer thanks, so it's definitely a deliberate feature, then!

Comment: `numpy` is not `sympy` aware.  But it appears that `sympy` has provided enough methods, that its objects can behave a lot like numeric scalars when used in object dtype arrays.  Object array math is slower, and rather hit-and-miss as to its coverage (compared to regular numeric dtype arrays).

Comment: More on doing math with object dtype arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51447460/location-of-documentation-on-special-methods-recognized-by-numpy/51447793#51447793.  It helps explain why multiplication works, but `sin` does not.

Answer (score 2):

This is just NumPy's support for arrays of objects. It is not specific to SymPy. NumPy examines the operands and finds not all of them are scalars; there are some objects involved. So it calls that object's `__mul__` or `__rmul__`, and puts the result into an array of objects. For example: mpmath objects,

```
>>> import mpmath as mp
>>> np.ones(5) * mp.mpf('1.23')
array([mpf('1.23'), mpf('1.23'), mpf('1.23'), mpf('1.23'), mpf('1.23')],
      dtype=object)
```

or lists:

```
>>> np.array([[2], 3])*5
array([list([2, 2, 2, 2, 2]), 15], dtype=object)
>>> np.array([2, 3])*[[1, 1], [2]]
array([list([1, 1, 1, 1]), list([2, 2, 2])], dtype=object)
```

> Can I expect to keep some of numpy's speed when working with arrays of this kind,

No. NumPy object arrays have no performance benefits over Python lists; there is probably more overhead in accessing elements than would be in a list. [Storing Python objects in a Python list vs. a fixed-length Numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232597/storing-python-objects-in-a-python-list-vs-a-fixed-length-numpy-array)

There is no reason to use such arrays if a more specific data structure is available.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across a relevant note in the latest `numpy` release notes  (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/release.html)

```
Comparison ufuncs accept dtype=object, overriding the default bool

This allows object arrays of symbolic types, which override == and other operators to return expressions, to be compared elementwise with np.equal(a, b, dtype=object).
```

I think that means this works, but didn't before:

```
In [9]: np.array([x+.1, 2*y])==np.array([.1+x, y*2])
Out[9]: array([ True,  True])
```